# Value of optional type 'NSDictionary??' not unwrapped

Tags: ios

I've been following a tutorial that was playing around with API, specifically the openweathermap api, and I ran into a problem and xCode gives me options to "Fix it with ! and ??", which unfortunately does not fix the issue either.

```
if let urlContent = data {
                do {
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
                print(jsonResult)
                print(jsonResult?["name"])  
                    if let description = ((jsonResult?["weather"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["description"] as? String {
                        print(description) 
                    } 
                } catch {      
                    print("JSON Processing Fail")                        
                }
```

Im getting an error on `if let description = ((jsonResult?["weather"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["description"] as? String`as a Value of optional type 'NSDictionary??' not unwrapped Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Swift's native type Array instead of NSArray.

```
do {
   if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? [String: Any] {   
       if let weatherArray = jsonResult["weather"] as? [[String:Any]],
          let dic = weatherArray.first, let description = dic["description"] as? String {
            print(description) 
        } 
   }

} catch {      
    print("JSON Processing Fail")                        
}
```